# Spring WebFlow - NullPointerException in setter method - how to handle nicely

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

Is there a magic value to place in messages.properties to capture the error condition where a NullPointerException is thrown during a setter method, In the same way there is [field].typeMismatch=[message], or does one have to suck up the NullPointerException and handle the situation in a validate method which would add an Error to the Errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you'd have to handle it yourself.

An NPE being thrown by a setter is highly unusual situation - a well-designed class would not normally do that.